# update data on file change?

Tags: c#, .net

```
    public DataUpdater(string file, ref DataTable data)
    {
        FileSystemWatcher fileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        fileWatcher.Path = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
        fileWatcher.Filter = Path.GetFileName(file);
        fileWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
        fileWatcher.Changed += (sender, e) =>
            {
                data = CSVParser.ParseCSV(file);
            };
    }
```

Hello, i'm trying to update a data table variable when a file changes but the output says i cant have a ref or out in the changed event. please help

Comment: ...because `ref` makes absolutely no sense there! you might wanna use `var` instead?

Comment: I originally didnt have the ref there but it keprt gaving me this output: Error 1 Cannot use ref or out parameter 'data' inside an anonymous method, lambda expression, or query expression C:\Users\Exus\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\FBLADesktopApplicationProgramming2013\FBLADesktopApplicationProgramming2013\DataClasses.cs 22 21 FBLADesktopApplicationProgramming2013

Comment: ooooh now i see, okaaaay... yes that is absolutely not possible, you cant set a value to a ref parameter from inside a lambda, i will post solution alternatives ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay what you are trying looks like a reasonable idea, **but** you cannot set values to `ref` parameters from within lambdas. Why? Well, a `ref` parameter gives you the right to access the provided variable **as long as the method runs**. Since, in fact, there is no way to know when the lambda runs, writing to this variable inside of it is therefore not allowed - it would be a backdoor for unlimited writing access to that variable.

Possible solution:

Change the signature of `DataUpdater` to something that gives permanent access to your `DataTable`.

```
public DataUpdater(string file, Action<DataTable> setter);
```

Call this constructor via `new DataUpdater(..., x => targetTable = x)` and change the line inside the lambda to `setter(CSVParser...);`

I hope this makes sense ;)